# Why is thunderbird grouping unrelated messages?

Tags: thunderbird

I have this annoying problem with thunderbird. It is grouping unrelated messages...

Any ideas what is going on? The node that expanded shows emails from two different people on different domains, so why are they grouped?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not grouping by recipient... it is threading. If someone hits reply on the first message, even if they change the subject, recipients, entire message body, it will send some extra header (I think it's "In-Reply-To:") that joins the messages so you see them like this.

To filter by recipient, use the filters instead (hotkey ctrl+shift+k).

Comment: Ah yes the plot thickens. I find email interesting I should read up on the different headers. Thanks...